# Sending Image via socket php

Tags: php, sockets

I am Developing a video chat app in PHP via sockets 
I am using Linux server 
The Client are connecting through Telnet 
Like Telnet 127.0.0.1 4444

And the code the send the text message to other Clients are below

```
$msg['pid'] = posix_getpid();
    $message = serialize( $msg );
    $f = fopen(self::PIPENAME, 'w+');
    if( !$f ) {
        echo "ERROR: Can't open PIPE for writting\n";
        return;
    }
    fwrite($f, $this->strlenInBytes($message) . $message );
    fclose($f)
```

Please tell me How can i send the Images ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia:

> Telnet is a network protocol used on the Internet or local area
>   networks to provide a bidirectional interactive **text-oriented**
>   communication facility...

I don't think there is a way to send images until you encode them in some way (e.g. BASE64) and decode them on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but if send the image through socket_write($sock,$string,strlen($string));
Then I think i don't need to convert it..
I am little bit confuse please let me know if i am correct..